# basic_stream_socket::async_read_some, but don't read

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Is there a function that is like `basic_stream_socket::async_read_some`, but does not do any reading, and instead just tells me that there is data available? I have the file handle of the socket, and a third-party library that does the actual reading.

`socket_base::bytes_readable` is not the answer, because it is synchronous.

Comment: "because it is synchronous" What would that mean? There are no synchronous or asynchronous functions. There are functions that may block and functions that never block. This one never blocks.

Comment: @n.m. I need a callback when the data is available, not a function that I need to poll (which is `bytes_available`).

Comment: "I need a callback when the data is available". Then say so in the question, because it says nothing like that.